# A better way of specifying the fields in a gtk.ListStore

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have a `ListStore` with a lot of fields, most of them the same:

```
store = gtk.ListStore(str,str,str,str,str,str,str,str,
            gtk.gdk.Pixbuf,gtk.gdk.Pixbuf,gtk.gdk.Pixbuf,gtk.gdk.Pixbuf,
            gtk.gdk.Pixbuf,gtk.gdk.Pixbuf,gtk.gdk.Pixbuf,gtk.gdk.Pixbuf,
            gtk.gdk.Pixbuf,gtk.gdk.Pixbuf,gtk.gdk.Pixbuf,gtk.gdk.Pixbuf,
            gtk.gdk.Pixbuf,gtk.gdk.Pixbuf,str,)
```

Is there a better way than this horrible mass of repetition?

EDIT: So this ended up:

```
store = gtk.ListStore( *(8*(str,)+14*(gtk.gdk.Pixbuf,)+(str,)) )
```

Less readable I guess but more programatically adaptable

Comment: Not sure this is the best answer, that looks awful...

Comment: @liberforce yeah as I said it's less readable - but at least this way I can make the allocation more dynamic

Comment: Then maybe it would be better to create a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_design_pattern) for that, instead of sparkling ugly unreadable stuff all over. You'd keep the flexibility and the readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you have control over the `ListStore` code, pack them into a `namedtuple` and make sure they dont shadow the built-in names.
2. If you don't have control over the `ListStore` code, pack them into a tuple and unpack the arguments via `gtk.ListStore(*yourtuple)`.